# has_secure_password password can't be blank rails 4.1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

We implemented the "has_secure_password" for authentication in rails 4.1. Here is the code:

```
    # == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  name            :string(255)
#  firstname       :string(255)
#  created_at      :datetime
#  updated_at      :datetime
#  password_digest :string(255)
#  lastname        :string(255)
#
```

(user.rb)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
end
```

(user_controllers.rb)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    u = User.new(user_params)
    if u.save
      render json: u, status: 200 #, location: u
    else
      render json: {errors: u.errors.messages}, status: 422
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :firstname, :lastname, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

When sending a post request to /users to create one, we are getting the "password can't be blank" error.
In addition, we tried to display the content of user_params, all the params are there except the password and password_confirmation.
Any idea?

Comment: Can you show the json you are sending?

Comment: we are sending this:
{"name":"Dave",
"firstname":"Rob",
"lastname":"Bert",
"password":"superpass",
"password_confirmation":"superpass"}

Comment: Can you include your form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the problem, it might help someone some day.
We were sending this Json :

```
{"name":"Dave", "firstname":"Rob", "lastname":"Bert", "password":"superpass", "password_confirmation":"superpass"}
```

the framework was expecting this:

```
{ "user" : {"name":"Dave", "firstname":"Rob", "lastname":"Bert", "password":"superpass", "password_confirmation":"superpass"}}
```

Simply forgot the user key at the beginnning...